# How can I output a pdf thats starts on the right hand side?

Tags: pdf

Some Ebook pdf files begin on the right side when viewed in a pdf viewer. Is there any way I can replicate this with a command in Latex?
My simple solution would be to add a blank page in the front, but there must be a better option. I'm using KOMA-Script's scrreprt, if that helps.

TY for your help!

Edit: Problem solved with \usepackage[pdfpagelayout=TwoPageRight]{hyperref}

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @sfRay Try adding `\pdfcatalog{/PageLayout /TwoPageRight}`.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Koma, but this is the default for the book class, and I'd be surprised if Koma didn't do that as well.  How do you know you don't already have that output?

Comment: @MarcelKrüger thank you for your help with TwoPageRight, I found the same command in the hyperref package

Comment: @sfRay If you ound the solution yourself, it is better to create a proper answer in the answer field below and to accept that. Then the question gets marked as answered (and you can earn reputation).

Comment: @Teepeemm maybe it's because I use report and not book. I know it because it starts with page 1 on the left in my pdf viewer. Setting pdfpagelayout=TwoPageRight in the hyperref package fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved with passing the option `pdfpagelayout=TwoPageRight` to [`hyperref`](//ctan.org/pkg/hyperref):

```
\usepackage[pdfpagelayout=TwoPageRight]{hyperref}
```